# Remove frameborder attribute on the iframe of Recaptcha

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, recaptcha, w3c-validation

I need to know where I can change this line of code of Google recaptcha code:

The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. I would like to change the frameborder="0" with in the iframe to something like border:none;.

when validating it gives an error saying "The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.".

Any ideas of how to fix this?

```
 <dd class="auto recaptcha">
    <p class="cap">ReCAPTCHA entry is for testing whether you are a human visitor and to prevent automated spam submissions.</p>
    <div class="recaptcha-item">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfaXscSAAAAAMcN5Mfvza9CyYfV7K5__BbQiPBN"></script>

<noscript>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfaXscSAAAAAMcN5Mfvza9CyYfV7K5__BbQiPBN" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript>                </div>

              <p><sup class="required">*</sup> = Required Fields</p>
    </dd>
```

[image: Screenshot of wf4's answer]

Screenshot of wf4's answer

Comment: if you don't post any code, people can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your edit. There is a script, `src = http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge` which will use javascript to create an iframe in your site, the `noscript` bit will be used if scripts are not available. so if you remove

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfaXscSAAAAAMcN5Mfvza9CyYfV7K5__BbQiPBN"></script>`

and the `<noscript> </noscript>` tags, BUT NOT THE CONTENT, then you can remove the  `frameborder="0"` which you don't want. so your complete code would be:

```
 <dd class="auto recaptcha">
<p class="cap">ReCAPTCHA entry is for testing whether you are a human visitor and to prevent automated spam submissions.</p>
<div class="recaptcha-item">


<iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfaXscSAAAAAMcN5Mfvza9CyYfV7K5__BbQiPBN" height="300" width="500"></iframe><br/>
<textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
            </div>

          <p><sup class="required">*</sup> = Required Fields</p>
</dd>
```

for the styling, this would also have been added using the script, this should be what you will need to include in your `head`

```
<style type="text/css">
.recaptchatable td img{display:block}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r1_c1{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') 0 -63px no-repeat;width:318px;height:9px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r2_c1{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') -18px 0 no-repeat;width:9px;height:57px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r2_c2{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') -27px 0 no-repeat;width:9px;height:57px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c1{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') 0 0 no-repeat;width:9px;height:63px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c2{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') -18px -57px no-repeat;width:300px;height:6px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c3{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') -9px 0 no-repeat;width:9px;height:63px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c1{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') -43px 0 no-repeat;width:171px;height:49px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c2{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') -36px 0 no-repeat;width:7px;height:57px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c4{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') -214px 0 no-repeat;width:97px;height:57px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r7_c1{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') -43px -49px no-repeat;width:171px;height:8px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r8_c1{background:url('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/sprite.png') -43px -49px no-repeat;width:25px;height:8px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_image_cell center img{height:57px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_image_cell center{height:57px}.recaptchatable .recaptcha_image_cell{background-color:white;height:57px}#recaptcha_area,#recaptcha_table{width:318px!important}.recaptchatable,#recaptcha_area tr,#recaptcha_area td,#recaptcha_area th{margin:0!important;border:0!important;padding:0!important;border-collapse:collapse!important;vertical-align:middle!important}.recaptchatable *{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:8pt;color:black;position:static;top:auto;left:auto;right:auto;bottom:auto}.recaptchatable #recaptcha_image{position:relative;margin:auto}.recaptchatable #recaptcha_image #recaptcha_challenge_image{display:block}.recaptchatable #recaptcha_image #recaptcha_ad_image{display:block;position:absolute;top:0}.recaptchatable img{border:0!important;margin:0!important;padding:0!important}.recaptchatable a,.recaptchatable a:hover{cursor:pointer;outline:none;border:0!important;padding:0!important;text-decoration:none;color:blue;background:none!important;font-weight:normal}.recaptcha_input_area{position:relative!important;width:153px!important;height:45px!important;margin-left:7px!important;margin-right:7px!important;background:none!important}.recaptchatable label.recaptcha_input_area_text{margin:0!important;padding:0!important;position:static!important;top:auto!important;left:auto!important;right:auto!important;bottom:auto!important;background:none!important;height:auto!important;width:auto!important}.recaptcha_theme_red label.recaptcha_input_area_text,.recaptcha_theme_white label.recaptcha_input_area_text{color:black!important}.recaptcha_theme_blackglass label.recaptcha_input_area_text{color:white!important}.recaptchatable #recaptcha_response_field{width:153px!important;position:relative!important;bottom:7px!important;padding:0!important;margin:15px 0 0 0!important;font-size:10pt}.recaptcha_theme_blackglass #recaptcha_response_field,.recaptcha_theme_white #recaptcha_response_field{border:1px solid gray}.recaptcha_theme_red #recaptcha_response_field{border:1px solid #cca940}.recaptcha_audio_cant_hear_link{font-size:7pt;color:black}.recaptchatable{line-height:1!important}#recaptcha_instructions_error{color:red!important}.recaptcha_only_if_privacy{float:right;text-align:right}#recaptcha-ad-choices{position:absolute;height:15px;top:0;right:0}#recaptcha-ad-choices img{height:15px}.recaptcha-ad-choices-collapsed{width:15px;height:15px;display:block}.recaptcha-ad-choices-expanded{width:75px;height:15px;display:none}#recaptcha-ad-choices:hover .recaptcha-ad-choices-collapsed{display:none}#recaptcha-ad-choices:hover .recaptcha-ad-choices-expanded{display:block}
.recaptcha_is_showing_audio .recaptcha_only_if_image,.recaptcha_isnot_showing_audio .recaptcha_only_if_audio,.recaptcha_had_incorrect_sol .recaptcha_only_if_no_incorrect_sol,.recaptcha_nothad_incorrect_sol .recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol{display:none !important}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks @wf4 it working fine. but does not have any styles. does any one knows how to remove this without affecting to the initial design

Comment: I've added the CSS taken from F12 Developer tools when the script is used.  @MaheshWijewardhana that should sort out the style for you.

Comment: i added your css. but it did not change anything. @wf4

Comment: aha, I just checked, that css will not work when the elements are within an iframe. What you will need to do (which will take quite a few minutes) is to add `iframe` before your css selectors... e.g. `.recaptchatable td img{display:block}` would become `iframe .recaptchatable td img{display:block}`. by default they would not cascade but this should work for you. Try a few first, if it starts to work, do the rest.

Comment: sorry to say that it does not affected any thing. please see the screenshot.

Comment: I'm even more sorry! Turns out that you can't. I've even been digging in an old site to see how I used to do it, that no longer works, I just get a security message. I have just posted a new answer as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so here is another solution...  The question was "Remove frameborder attribute on the iframe of Recaptcha".
This question must have come about as a result of the w3c validator. In your code there is a script which will inject HTML into your page, doing so will include all the HTML and CSS needed to style the content. 
My first answer was to remove this script and use just the `iframe` in the `<noscript>` tags, however, this is not the problem. The problem is the content of the `<noscript>` tags and not the actual recapthcha. So my second answer is to do one of the following:

A: Remove the `frameborder="0"` from the `iframe`

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfaXscSAAAAAMcN5Mfvza9CyYfV7K5__BbQiPBN" height="300" width="500"></iframe>
```

which would fix the validation problem.

B: Remove the entire `<noscript>` section if you don't want an unformatted form when scripts are not available.

There are several other attempts to style the contents of an iframe but they use javascript and modern browsers will not allow this when the sites are not part of the same domain.